# c - cheak readable bytes

Tags: c, memory, ram, readable

need little help form you guys

i just wanna to cheak if the byte is readable or not, i have search for sulution but not find

hope you will help me

i have this code i need if tag that cheak if byte is readable

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
   float ramsize;
   char *ch;
   unsigned int j=128,readbyte;
   long i;
   MEMORYSTATUSEX statex;
   statex.dwLength = sizeof (statex);
   GlobalMemoryStatusEx (&statex);
   ramsize = statex.ullTotalPhys;
   for(i=0;i<ramsize;i = i+1)
   {
       ch = (char*) i;
       readbyte = *ch;
       // if readbyte is readable
       printf("you have readable byte in address: %x , that contain in Binary:",&readbyte);
       for(i=0;i<8;i++)
       {
           if(readbyte&j)
               printf("1");
           else
               printf("0");
           j=j>>1;
       }
       putchar('\n');
       // if readbyte is not readable
       printf("Sorry: you cant read this byte: %x",&readbyte);
   }
}
```

Comment: first, why do you not taking `unsigned chat j = 128;` ? this is the error..

Comment: sorry i was taking 2 bytes and i forget to change it

Comment: but thats not my problem its just a little error

Comment: Why do you want to check an address?  Answering this, may help us to give you a better/different way to solve your root issue.

Comment: Please correct "cheak" -> "check".

Comment: i have a college home work to search for a string in RAM and print the address of string if i found it, but every time i try to do that the program is crash cause there is bytes unreadable in my RAM but i wanna to cheak if the byte is unreadable or not

Comment: I doubt Windows allows you to access memory that is not allocated to your program.

Answer (score 0):

If a byte is not readable the OS will send a signal to your process. You need to catch that signal or your program will terminate.

Read up on signals in your course textbook.